# Ejecutar POST con AJAX en Javascript puro

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Tengo este formulario:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="addProductForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="seleccionarCategoria" name="seleccionarCategoria">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seleccionarNombre" name="seleccionarNombre">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="seleccionarImagen" name="seleccionarImagen" aria-describedby="seleccionarImagen">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seleccionarMarca" name="seleccionarMarca">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seleccionarMedida" name="seleccionarMedida">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seleccionarPrecio" name="selecionarPrecio">
    <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" name="seleccionarEstado">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

Lo hago con ajax mediante la siguiente funcion:

```
function ajaxAdd(elemento, direccion, destino){

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var datos = document.getElementById(elemento);
    var destino = document.getElementById(destino);

    datos.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        var formu = new FormData(datos);

        ajax.open('POST', direccion);
        ajax.onload = () => {
            if(ajax.status == 200 && ajax.responseText != 'error'){
                destino.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                console.warn('si->' + ajax.readyState);
                alertify.success('Acción Exitosa');
            }
            else{
                console.error('error de conexion-> estatus: ' + ajax.status + ', ready estatus: ' + ajax.readyState);
                alertify.error('Ocurrió un Error');
            }   
        }

        ajax.send(formu);
    });
}

//Asi uso la funcion ajaxAdd:
ajaxAdd('addProductForm', 'php/accionesCatalogo.php', 'accordion');
```

Cabe recalcar que lo quiero hacer con puro javascript, no con jquery. Por ultimo el archivo acciones catalogo.php tiene esto:

```
<?php

    include_once('catalogoprivado.php');

    if(isset($_POST["seleccionarCategoria"]) && isset($_POST["seleccionarNombre"]) && isset($_FILES["seleccionarImagen"]) &&
       isset($_POST["seleccionarMarca"]) && isset($_POST["seleccionarMedida"]) && isset($_POST["seleccionarPrecio"]) &&
       isset($_POST["seleccionarEstado"])
    ){
        if ($_POST["seleccionarEstado"] == 'on') {
            $estado = '1';
        }else{
            $estado = '0';
        }

        $folder = $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];
        $imagen = file_get_contents($folder);
        $entradaMultiple = 
            $_POST["seleccionarCategoria"]. "," . $_POST["seleccionarNombre"] . "," . $_POST["seleccionarMarca"] . 
                "," . $_POST["seleccionarMedida"] . "," . $_POST["seleccionarPrecio"] . "," . $estado . "," . $imagen;
        $base->insertar(
            'productos', 'pertenece_categoria, nombre_producto, marca, medida, precio, estado, logo', $entradaMultiple
        );
    }

?>
```

he revisado por todas partes pero no veo porque no me realizar la consulta, (en este caso busco agregar a la base de datos lo ingresado en el formulario, que se cargue con el ajax por medio del archivo php citado) y aqui esta la funcion insertar mencionada

```
function insertar($tabla, $campos, $valores){
    $conexion = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DBNAME);
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO $tabla ($campos) VALUES ('$valores')";
    $sqli_resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
}
```

Comment: probe con 'setrequestheader' y  reemplazar 'on load' por 'onreadystatechange' pero nada funciona, no veo porque. Avisenme por favor si me hizo falta agregar alguna parte del codigo.

Comment: *he revisado por todas partes pero no veo porque no me realizar la consulta* indica en la pregunta cuál ha sido el resultado de esas revisiones que dices que has hecho por todas partes. Por ejemplo: ¿verificaste por un método simple que hay comunicación entre cliente (Ajax) y servidor (PHP)? ¿verificaste que los datos llegan correctamente al servidor? ¿verificaste que la respuesta del servidor llega al cliente? ¿En qué punto encuentras el problema?

Comment: En estos casos la primera verificación que hay que hacer sería: `var_dump($_POST);` y `var_dump($_FILES);` y revisar en la consola de JS si se ve alguna respuesta y qué respuesta es.

Comment: la respuesta es codigo 200 del estatus y del onreadystate es 4, no estoy seguro de si eso es lo que deberia pasar, siempre me lleva al caso 'console.error('error de conexion-> estatus: ' + ajax.status + ', ready estatus: ' + ajax.readyState);'. No tengo ni idea de cual sera el error pues es mi primera vez tratando con ajax, y mi segunda pregunta en stackoverflow asi que disculpenme si no puedo introducir codigo correctamente. por ultimo, si, si hay conexion entre php y JS, porque funciona con otro formulario que no tiene imagenes, sospecho que en el tema de las imagenes esta el error

Comment: a lo mejor no estoy transformando correctamente a bytes la imagen para subirla a la base de datos (que es parte de lo que quiero hacer)

Comment: Código 200 significa que la petición se envió al servidor y que esté respondió OK, recibido. Pero eso no significa que todo está OK. Si no manejas bien las cosas en el servidor no obtendrás de vuelta la respuesta esperada. Como ya dije, en el servidor revisa POST y FILES y en el cliente puedes mostrar por consola la respuesta de Ajax con un `console.log(ajax);` antes del `if`. Parece que están ocurriendo errores y hay que depurarlos.

Comment: sospecho que se debe a que no estoy usando correctamente FILES dado que esta funcion trabaja perfecto con los POST, es decir con los puros texto, puedes porfavor revisar si estoy extrayendo correctamente los bytes del input seleccionarImagen?, según los otros tutoriales así es como se suben imagenes a una base de datos y ese es mi objetivo con este código.

Comment: Puede que ese sea un problema, debes usar el valor de `name` para recuperar los datos, quizá debes ponerlo así: `$folder = $_FILES["seleccionarImagen"]["tmp_name"];` PERO no *sospeches* nada, que no estás viendo una película de intriga, estás programando y cuando programas no tienes que *sospechar*, tienes que ***depurar***. ¿Me explico? Cuando depuras, encuentras el error y lo resuelves en 5 minutos, cuando sospechas te puedes pasar 5 días sospechando.

Comment: Oye, podrias colocar el como usas la funcion `ajaxAdd` y con que valores la ejecutas?, esa informacion creo que es vital. por cierto estabas comparando mal las cosas en la parte de `PHP`, ahi te hice unas pequeñas correcciones usando `&&`. Tambien en la parte de javascript tenias suelto un parentesis que no se necesitaba `)`.

Comment: claro, lo olvidaba: ajaxAdd('addProductForm', 'php/accionesCatalogo.php', 'accordion');

Comment: Bueno, en primera decir que no debes usar el evento submit para intentar prevenirlo, puesto que el evento submit se ejecutaria antes que el `preventDefault`, esto ya me ha pasado a mi, lo que deberias hacer es que en vez de estar constantemente añadiendo un evento `submit` al form, deberas añadirle mas bien un evento `click` al boton que se encarga de hacer el submit, y prevenir el evento pero de ese boton y `NO` del form.

Comment: No, @Riven, es preferible escuchar el `submit` que el clic del botón, porque si pulsas `ENTER` en un campo de texto el formulario se procesará `submit` sin que el evento del botón intervenga.

Comment: @Triby si, pero escuchar ese mismo evento y prevenirlo de esa forma en mi caso falla, el formulario se subscribre de todas maneras, quiza se deba a que estoy usando firefox...

Comment: @Riven, Firefox es mi navegador de preferencia y no me ha pasado eso, haces clic en el botón, se lanza el evento `onclick` y después el `onsubmit`, ahí es donde hay que usar `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Esta misma funcion la utilice con otro formulario que solo tiene una entrada de puro texto y funciona perfectamente, así que probe eliminando las entradas de checkbox y archivos, pero aun me sigue diciendo readyState = 4 y status = 200 en el ELSE que utilizo para marcar un error de ajax

Comment: Ahhh entiendo, entonces el problema en mi caso viene porque el evento que seguramente que se esta previniendo es el click y no el `submit`, pero entonces porque al indicar como evento `submit` e indicarle el `preventDefault` igual no funciona? :c, es extraño, aun me sigue sin funcionar :/, a lo mejor es porque estoy en linux, no se que este pasando xd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo diría que el problema está por aquí:

En el formulario el campo se llama "seleccionarImagen" pero estás leyendo `$_FILES['imagen']` y por lo tanto `$imagen` queda vacío.

```
$folder = $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];
$imagen = file_get_contents($folder);
```

Luego, acá hay un problema en la concatenación de los valores:

```
$entradaMultiple = 
      $_POST["seleccionarCategoria"]
    . "," 
    . $_POST["seleccionarNombre"] 
    . "," 
    . $_POST["seleccionarMarca"] 
    . "," 
    . $_POST["seleccionarMedida"] 
    . "," 
    . $_POST["seleccionarPrecio"] 
    . "," 
    . $estado 
    . "," 
    . $imagen;
```

Si estás usando `$entradaMultiple` para hacer la inserción directamente, entonces la consulta te está fallando porque no estás rodeando con comillas los campos no numéricos. Justamente, `$imagen` es una cadena (no se los otros campos) y deberías concatenar la variable así:

```
$entradaMultiple = 
      $_POST["seleccionarCategoria"]
    . "," 
    . $_POST["seleccionarNombre"] 
    . "," 
    . $_POST["seleccionarMarca"] 
    . "," 
    . $_POST["seleccionarMedida"] 
    . "," 
    . $_POST["seleccionarPrecio"] 
    . "," 
    . $estado 
    . "," 
    . '"' . $imagen . '"';
```

Por otro lado, si así estás armando tus consultas entonces también estás teniendo un problema de inyección de código. Deberías leer sobre "consultas preparadas" para mejorar la seguridad! :)

Comment: tienes razon, todos los campos. Todos los campos son de cadena a excepcion del de precio y estado e imagen que son int, tinyint y blob, el error estoy seguro que es por allí ya que me ha pasado antes, gracias, de verdad.

Comment: de nada, espero puedas avanzar!  :D

Answer (score 0):

halle la solucion definitiva: el error estaba en dos partes, la primera en el HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="addProductForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="seleccionarCategoria" name="seleccionarCategoria">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="seleccionarNombre" name="seleccionarNombre">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="seleccionarImagen" name="seleccionarImagen" aria-describedby="seleccionarImagen">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="seleccionarMarca" name="seleccionarMarca">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="seleccionarMedida" name="seleccionarMedida">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="seleccionarPrecio" name="**selecionarPrecio**">
<input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" name="seleccionarEstado">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
```

Si se fijan, esta mal escrito, pero en el codigo php esta solicitandose como seleccionarPrecio, no selecionarPrecio. Por otro lado no estaba haciendo bien las comparaciones de valores, detalle que aquí me ayudaron a resolver